# create UICollectionViewController subclass and add as a childviewcontroller

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uicollectionview

I am new to iOS development. I want to create collectionView in two different view controllers with same UI.I want to create only one UICollectionView and resuse it on different view controller instead of create separate collectionViews . On approach i can follow is to create the UICollectionViewController subclass and add this on my viewcontrollers as a childviewcontroller, but not sure if this is the correct approach  do not know  how addChildViewcontroller works and how to pass data between child and parent viewcontrollers. It would be great if someone can help on this. If any sample code is available to achive this please let me know.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a Set of Answers you can use,

- My source Code is ParentViewController and ChildViewController are
  same viewController to be declared.
- First you create the ParentViewController and add the
  UICollectionView then set the Cell size in ParentViewController.
- Second you create UICollectionViewCell in same parentViewController,
  then add what u need Label or Buttons to be declare.
- In ParentViewController class declare 'UICollectionViewDelegate',

Ex: class MyViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate

- Then Create UICollectionViewDelegate methods and i have put my
  methods below,

func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return arrayvalue.count
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {


    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("reuseIdentifier", forIndexPath: indexPath)

    // Configure the cell

    let baseView = cell.viewWithTag(101)
    let titleLabel = baseView?.viewWithTag(102) as! UILabel

    titleLabel.text = arrayvalue[indexPath.row] as String

    return cell
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView,
    layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
    sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {

     return CGSizeMake(CellSize)
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
{
    collectionView.deselectItemAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated:true)

    let storyBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "storyboardName", bundle: nil)
    let name: classname = storyBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("reuseIdentifier") as! AnotherViewController

    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(name, animated: true)
}
```

- Very Important to give storyboard 'reuseIdentifier' value and also
  give inside the class cellForItemAtIndexPath reuseIdentifier, example this line

  ```
  let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("reuseIdentifier", forIndexPath: indexPath)
  ```

This code was working for me...

Answer (score 3):

You can pass around the same collection view controller instance. Add it in viewWillAppear and remove in viewDidDisappear in first and second classes. Here is a sample code that you could use,

```
extension UIColor {
class func randomColor() -> UIColor {
    let red = CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(255)) / 255.0
    let green = CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(255)) / 255.0
    let blue = CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(255)) / 255.0

    return UIColor(red: red, green: green, blue: blue, alpha: 1.0)
}
```

}

```
class MyCollectionViewController: UICollectionViewController {

    let  data: [UIColor]

    init(data: [UIColor]) {
        self.data = data
        let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        layout.itemSize = CGSizeMake(100, 100)
        layout.scrollDirection = UICollectionViewScrollDirection.Vertical

        super.init(collectionViewLayout: layout)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        collectionView?.registerClass(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "cell")
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return data.count
    }

    override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
        cell.backgroundColor = data[indexPath.item]
        return cell
    }
}


class FirstViewController: UIViewController {

    lazy var myData:[UIColor] = {
        var allData = [UIColor]()
        for i in 0 ..< 20 {
            allData.append(UIColor.randomColor())
        }
        return allData
    }()

    var collectionViewController: MyCollectionViewController!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        collectionViewController = MyCollectionViewController(data: self.myData)

        let barButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Show next", style: .Plain, target: self, action: "showNext:")
        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = barButton
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        let collectionView = collectionViewController.view
        collectionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        view.addSubview(collectionView)
        addChildViewController(collectionViewController)

        collectionView.topAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(view.topAnchor).active = true
        collectionView.bottomAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(view.bottomAnchor).active = true
        collectionView.leftAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(view.leftAnchor).active = true
        collectionView.rightAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(view.rightAnchor).active = true

        collectionViewController.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
    }

    override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidDisappear(animated)

        collectionViewController.willMoveToParentViewController(nil)
        collectionViewController.view.removeFromSuperview()
        collectionViewController.removeFromParentViewController()
    }

    func showNext(sender: AnyObject) {
        let secondViewController = SecondViewController(collectionViewController: collectionViewController)
        navigationController?.pushViewController(secondViewController, animated: true)
    }
}

class SecondViewController: UIViewController {

    var collectionViewController: MyCollectionViewController!

    init(collectionViewController: MyCollectionViewController) {
        self.collectionViewController = collectionViewController
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        let collectionView = collectionViewController.view

        view.addSubview(collectionView)
        collectionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        addChildViewController(collectionViewController)

        collectionView.topAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(view.topAnchor).active = true
        collectionView.bottomAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(view.bottomAnchor).active = true
        collectionView.leftAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(view.leftAnchor).active = true
        collectionView.rightAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(view.rightAnchor).active = true

        collectionViewController.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
    }

    override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidDisappear(animated)

        collectionViewController.willMoveToParentViewController(nil)
        collectionViewController.view.removeFromSuperview()
        collectionViewController.removeFromParentViewController()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Problem is how can i pass data source from FirstViewController to MyCollectionViewController and how   MyCollectionViewController respond back to FirstViewController for any event?

Comment: Why do you want to pass data source. Just set one view controller delegate or change it when you want to respond to event. Or create your own MyCollectionViewControllerDelegate

Comment: When my FirstViewController is loaded I want to create number of items based on the data source(like array). Thats why i need to pass array to MyCollectionViewController from FirstViewController to create number of collection items.MyCollectionViewController itself do not know how many items need to be created.

Comment: Pass your data in the initializer or set it when you like, updated with the example where passed data is array of UICOlor.

Comment: I am able to add UICollectionViewController as a childViewController but collectionviewcontroller captured all the screen and starting from top. How can i set the frame